# Using Barcode Number as Primary Key in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have problem to define the `barcode number` as the `primary key` at Item table. Previously I use the usual ID as the primary key.

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');            
    $table->integer('price');
}
```

Now, when I want to change the type of id to `integer` barcode number, it does not work.

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id', 15)->unsigned;
    $table->string('name');            
    $table->integer('price');
}
```

I got the error below after running `php artisan migrate`

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `inventory`.`orders` (errno: 150 "Foreign 
 key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

The Order table below has foreign key reference to Item table.

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Do you have datas in your items table

Comment: Yes. I want to access the item table from sale table.

Comment: I removed the phpmyadmin tag here because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. hopefully it will work

```
 Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
```

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('item_id');
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: I have changed to unsigned() but the error is still there

Comment: check my ans again bro

Answer (score 1):

Try change this ,

```
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
```

> $table->unsignedBigInteger('item_id');

```
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

or how about this

```
 $table->integer('item_id',15)->unsigned();
```